# SharePoint attaching the debugger

Tags: sharepoint

Whenever I try to attach the debugger to my SharePoint project it is taking 5+ minutes to actually attach. Does anyone know of a way to speed this up?

Comment: In my experience you should be thankful it attaches at all :-)

Comment: This is not normal.  I suppose it may depend on how much memory you have on your SharePoint box (I would try to have around 2G, but you can get away with 1.5G).  Keep looking for a solution as 5+ minutes is not something you want to live with.

Comment: I have done some debugging in SharePoint myself. Kirk has the right idea. Make sure you have enough RAM. RAM is crucial on a system running SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if this is because its doing a load of debugging information. Do you have symbols services set up, and auto loading of debugging symbols?